# Change background for first child using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this html markup which I can't change due to my theme.

```
<div class="x-breadcrumb-wrap">
  <div class="x-container max width">
    <div class="x-breadcrumbs"><a href="https://www.domain.com"><span class="home"><i class="x-icon-home" data-x-icon="&#xf015;"></i></span></a> <span class="delimiter"><i class="x-icon-angle-right" data-x-icon="&#xf105;"></i></span> <a href="/guides/">Guides</a> <span class="delimiter"><i class="x-icon-angle-right" data-x-icon="&#xf105;"></i></span>      <span class="current"><a href="/guides/my-guide/"> london</a> <span class="delimiter"><i class="x-icon-angle-right" data-x-icon="&#xf105;"></i></span> <span class="current"><a href="/guides/my-guide/stays">Stays</a> <span class="delimiter"><i class="x-icon-angle-right" data-x-icon="&#xf105;"></i></span>      <span class="current">Venue</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to remove the background for the first:child (i.e. home icon) but using the code below the background is removed for subsequent links in the breadcrumbs.

```
.x-breadcrumb-wrap a {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  padding: 1px 6px 1px 6px;
  text-shadow: none !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.13em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.x-breadcrumb-wrap a:first-child {
  background: transparent;
}
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector isn't working as expected because it is selecting all of the descendant `a` elements that are a first child.

You need to use the [direct child selector, `>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), in order to only target the direct child `a` element of the `.x-breadcrumbs` element. In doing so, only the first child in the `.x-breadcrumbs` element is selected rather than all of the descendant elements that happen to be the first child of their parent element.

```
.x-breadcrumb-wrap .x-breadcrumbs > a:first-child {
  background: transparent;
}
```